# Screen scraping web page containing button with AJAX

Tags: c#, ajax, webbrowser-control, screen-scraping

I am trying to automate some of our processes, one includes logging in to an external web page, clicking a link to expand details, then grab all details displayed.

I have got the process logging in, and can grab all of the details once they are expanded.

The problem is with clicking the link. The link is defined like below (I have removed what the `Submit` method actually does as the code is long and probably irrelevant. Obviously the `img` is placeholder just as an example):

```
<a id="form:SummarySubView:closedToggleControl" onclick="A4J.AJAX.Submit(...); return false;" href="#">
    <img ... />
</a>
```

I use this data as below:

```
void browser_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    WebBrowser browser = (WebBrowser)sender;

    HtmlElement expandDetails = browser.Document.GetElementById("form:SummarySubView:closedToggleControl");
    //When open ID for element is "form:SummarySubView:openToggleControl"

    if(expandDetails == null) //If already expanded
    {
        //Stuff
    }
    else
    {
        expandDetails.InvokeMember("click"); //Click on element to run AJAX
    }
}
```

Upon running `expandDetails.InvokeMember("click");` `browser_DocumentCompleted` gets called again as expected but the document is same as before and `expandDetails` is found again with the "closed" id. This means that the details I am looking for are never shown.

How do I get access to the document AFTER the AJAX script runs correctly?

Adding a `Timer` to delay checking the document doesn't seem to have worked.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So a really simple solution seems to have worked. My code now looks like:

```
void browser_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    WebBrowser browser = (WebBrowser)sender;

    HtmlElement expandDetails = browser.Document.GetElementById("form:SummarySubView:closedToggleControl");
    //When open ID for element is "form:SummarySubView:openToggleControl"

    if(expandDetails == null) //If already expanded
    {
        //Stuff
    }
    else
    {
        expandDetails.InvokeMember("click"); //Click on element to run AJAX

        while (expandDetails != null)
        {
            expandDetails = browser.Document.GetElementById("form:SummarySubView0:closedToggleControl");

            Application.DoEvents();
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(200);
        }

        //Stuff
    }
}
```

So running the `while` loop works fine for my case.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, first off, the document.complete event will fire for ALL frames in the page.  So if you have 5 Iframes you will get 6 document complete events.

So you will need to check to see if you are actually the top level window or not.
Doing that alone may fix your problem.

```
private void WebBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        WebBrowser wb = sender as WebBrowser;
        //check to make sure we are on the TOP-level page.
        if (wb.Document.Window.Parent == null)
        {
            //do whatever else you need to here
        }
    }
```

If that doesn't do it, you can just use a timer to wait a few seconds after the document completes.

```
 public partial class Form1 : Form
 {
    Timer t;
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        webBrowser1.DocumentCompleted += WebBrowser1_DocumentCompleted;
    }
    private void WebBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        WebBrowser wb = sender as WebBrowser;

        //check to make sure we are on the TOP-level page.
        if (wb.Document.Window.Parent == null)
        {
            t = new Timer();
            t.Tick += (Timersender, eventargs) =>
            {
                //do whatever else you need to here
                t.Stop();
            };
            t.Interval = 2000; //wait 2 seconds for the document to complete
            t.Start();
        }
    }
}
```

You could tweak the timer to be longer or shorter as needed. But that should get you what you need.

Comment: So the document is complete before the AJAX function is applied? I will give it a go...

Comment: I don't know what website you are viewing. They can code it any way they want. But yes its very possible for a website to start calling ajax methods after document.complete fires by hooking into window.onload from javascript or $(document).ready from jQuery.   What I am saying is that at the least you should be checking if the document.complete event that is firing is coming from the top-level window. And if doing that isn't enough, you can add a timer to wait a few seconds while other ajax completes.

Comment: So I have added in a `Timer` and it doesn't seem to work. No matter how long I set the `Timer` it still shows the "pre-clicked" document.